# How to programmatically attach with server instance through vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to attach my database, that resided in the MyData directory of my application folder, to the instance of SQL server on client's machine.  How to do it?

Could any body give me vb.net code for that so my application does it when run for the first time?

Someone suggested me

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    ' Dim vrMyConString As String=
    Dim conn As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection ' = New SqlConnection(vrMyConString)
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_attach_db 'e:\dbTest.mdf', 'e:\dbTest.ldf'"
    'conn.connectionstring = 
    conn.open()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.executenonquery()
```

but on conn.open, it returns error, Object reference not set to an instance of object
Thanks

Comment: Google is an awesome search engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my Vb.net application.

Make sure sure your connection string: `vrMyConString` is correct and pointing to your database and with the correct details and it should work

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
conn = New SqlConnection(vrMyConString )

conn.Open()
```

Comment: I am sorry, actually I wanted to ask how to ATTACH my DB to the instance of SQL Server Express.  Could you please modify my code.  The code I gave above did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ADO.NET provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Linq to SQL or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) API.